# Identify mutual records based on multiple columns in Google Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Say I have the following BigQuery table:

```sql
WITH my_table AS (
  SELECT '2024-01-01' AS date, 1 AS session_id, 'a' AS client_id, NULL AS customer_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2024-01-01' AS date, 2 AS session_id, 'a' AS client_id, 'z' AS customer_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2024-01-01' AS date, 3 AS session_id, 'b' AS client_id, 'z' AS customer_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2024-01-01' AS date, 4 AS session_id, 'c' AS client_id, 'y' AS customer_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2024-01-01' AS date, 5 AS session_id, 'd' AS client_id, NULL AS customer_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2024-01-01' AS date, 6 AS session_id, 'd' AS client_id, 'x' AS customer_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2024-01-01' AS date, 7 AS session_id, 'e' AS client_id, 'x' AS customer_id
)

SELECT *
FROM my_table
```

[image]

Goal is to add a new column which brings together same client_ids OR same customer_ids. In the example, the first 3 lines should get the same user_id, because either client_id or customer_id belong together. Same for last 3 lines. Desired result:

[image]

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Wasn't able to get the new column user_id, but other part works here.         
`SELECT   my_table.session_id, my_table.client_id,my_table.customer_id,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER () as _key
FROM my_table
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
  (my_table.session_id,my_table.client_id, my_table.customer_id)
)
ORDER BY my_table.session_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take on this:

I assumed that the column `client_id` is never null and the columns `client_id` and `customer_id` will not ever collide.

It probably is kind of a hack around the problem and the `user_id` column does not goes 1 by 1. But it's a start.

```sql
WITH my_table AS (
  SELECT '2024-01-01' AS date, 1 AS session_id, 'a' AS client_id, NULL AS customer_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2024-01-01' AS date, 2 AS session_id, 'a' AS client_id, 'z' AS customer_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2024-01-01' AS date, 3 AS session_id, 'b' AS client_id, 'z' AS customer_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2024-01-01' AS date, 4 AS session_id, 'c' AS client_id, 'y' AS customer_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2024-01-01' AS date, 5 AS session_id, 'd' AS client_id, NULL AS customer_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2024-01-01' AS date, 6 AS session_id, 'd' AS client_id, 'x' AS customer_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2024-01-01' AS date, 7 AS session_id, 'e' AS client_id, 'x' AS customer_id
), all_data AS (
  SELECT t1.*, t2.client_id AS client_id_extra,
  FROM my_table t1
  LEFT JOIN my_table t2
  ON t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
), listing AS (
  SELECT client_id, STRING_AGG(client_id_extra) AS listing FROM all_data
  GROUP BY client_id
)
SELECT t.*, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY listing)
FROM my_table t
JOIN listing l
ON t.client_id = l.client_id
```

Comment: Both of your assumptions are fine in this case! The STRING_AGG() section is what I was missing. Your answer really helps and I will flag it as the accepted answer. Btw, replacing RANK() with DENSE_RANK() solved the fact that the user_id was not going 1 by 1. Thank you!